# GCM is not sending the push notification to offline user upon login... dont know what I am missing?

Tags: java, android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

The phone I am trying to receive the push notification from is not receiving it when the user is offline and comes online, the regId and the result is returned so not sure what is stopping it, not receiving an error either...

EDIT:
I have a user offline and then he would come online, and the message would not be pushed to him, only if the user is online at the time of the push...

Here is the code on server side:

```
// //BELOW FOR GCM
function notifyDetails(to, from, msg, itemId,  itemName, fromName, type) {

User.findOne({_id: to}, function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            throw err; 
        } else {
                callNotify();
            function callNotify() {
                console.log("the from is " + results.reg_id);
                if(results != null) {
                    request(
                { method: 'POST',
                uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': GOOGLE API KEY
                },

                    "registration_ids": [results.reg_id],
                    "data": {
                        "notifyFromUserId": from,
                        "notifyMsg": msg,
                        "notifyItemId": itemId,
                        "notifyItemName": itemName,
                        "notifyFromName": fromName,
                        "notifyType": type


                    },
                 //default 4 weeks (this is in seconds)
                    //"time_to_live": 20000
                })
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if(error) {
                    throw error;
                } else {

                    }

                });
                }

        }
            }


    });



}
```

On android manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".modular.MSGReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="package.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".modular.MSGService" />
```

The MSGService file:

```
public class MSGService extends IntentService {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    NotificationManager manager;

    public MSGService() {
        super("MSGService");
    }

    String TAG = Constants.DEBUG;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("Chat", 0);
        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error");
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error");
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Received: " + extras.getString("notifyMsg"));
                String notifyFromUserId, notifyMsg, notifyItemId, notifyItemName, notifyFromName;
                int notifyType;

                notifyFromUserId = extras.getString("notifyFromUserId");
                notifyMsg = extras.getString("notifyMsg");
                notifyItemId = extras.getString("notifyItemId");
                notifyItemName = extras.getString("notifyItemName");
                notifyFromName = extras.getString("notifyFromName");
                notifyType = extras.getInt("notifyType");
                sendNotification(notifyFromUserId, notifyMsg, notifyItemId, notifyItemName, notifyFromName, notifyType);


                }
        }
        MSGReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notifyFromUserId, String notifyMsg, String notifyItemId,
                                  String notifyItemName, String notifyFromName, int notifyType) {

        //the data that you want passed to the new class
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        Intent newIntentMsg = new Intent();


            data.putString("userId", notifyItemId);
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
            profileIntent.putExtras(data);
            newIntentMsg = profileIntent;



        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification.setContentTitle(notifyItemName);
        notification.setContentText(notifyMsg);
        notification.setTicker("New Message !");
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000,
                newIntentMsg, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        manager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, notification.build());
    }
}
```

The receiver file:

```
public class MSGReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    //Call a new intent and grab the data passed from the nodejs (extras)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Intent msgrcv = new Intent(context, MSGService.class);
        msgrcv.putExtra("notifyFromUserId", extras.getString("notifyFromUserId"));
        msgrcv.putExtra("notifyMsg", extras.getString("notifyMsg"));
        msgrcv.putExtra("notifyItemId", extras.getString("notifyItemId"));
            msgrcv.putExtra("notifyItemName", extras.getString("notifyItemName"));
            msgrcv.putExtra("notifyFromName", extras.getString("notifyFromName"));
            msgrcv.putExtra("notifyType", extras.getInt("notifyType"));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
        startWakefulService(context,msgrcv);
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: The message send from the server looks good to me, could you show more of your manifest. Also the code on the client side is no longer the recommended way of receiving GCM messages on Android. I'd suggest having a look at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: from and data are sufficient not context or intent needed? Not sure how to include it...

Answer (score 0):

1. What response you receive from GCM server when try to send push message? Please post response here. Also you can diagnose where is your problem with [my test push server](http://goo.gl/YEXjjl) help.
2. In MSGReceveier.onReceve you do unneceessary work when repack intent. Just set component for existing intent and pass it to your service:

   ```
   onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                                            MSGService.class.getName());
       startWakefulService(context,msgrcv);
       setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
   }
   ```

Comment: Not sure what you are replacing there exactly can you retype it with the entire code, and it seems to be working now, I think it took a bit of time to register the app or something... but I do have the issue where it is not working if I am offline and come online, the app does not receive it when I sign in... Look at the edit I added above, thanks

Comment: I edited method onReceive in my answer, you don't need read and put extras in onReceive method, you need just setComponent and route your intent to Service. Make sure that you set this parameter "delay_while_idle": true in your post request. If it is "false" it means GCM will not delivery messages if your device was idle (offline).

Comment: but if I am using wakelock then it should not matter no? I heard it can affect that too?

Comment: also, then why is startWakefulService using msgrcv what would go in its place?